# Can't connect to mysql server on '{host}' while using langchain SQLDatabase

Tags: python, langchain

I'm trying to connect a mysql database to langchain using SQLDatabase from langchain.utilities on my jupyter notebook.
I'm using the command SQLDatabase.from_uri(). It gives me an error. If I use sqlalchemy and create an engine, the engine object gets created but engine.connect() doesn't work. The whole process works fine when using pymysql. I can even pass sql queries by creating a cursor and everything works well there so it shouldn't be a problem on mysql server side even though I fiddled with the cnf file.
I'm a top-to-bottom approach kinda guy and might not have my basics clear. Please help!

```
from langchain.utilities import SQLDatabase
import pymysql
username = "root"
password = "xxxxxx"
host = 'localhost'
database = 'atliq_tshirts'
SQLDatabase.from_uri(f"mysql+pymysql://{username}:{password}@{host/{database}",sample_rows_in_table_info = 3)
```

Error log:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
gaierror                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py:644, in Connection.connect(self, sock)
    643 try:
--> 644     sock = socket.create_connection(
    645         (self.host, self.port), self.connect_timeout, **kwargs
    646     )
    647     break

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\socket.py:827, in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address, all_errors)
    826 exceptions = []
--> 827 for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
    828     af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\socket.py:962, in getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags)
    961 addrlist = []
--> 962 for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
    963     af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res

gaierror: [Errno 11003] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py:3280, in Engine._wrap_pool_connect(self, fn, connection)
   3279 try:
-> 3280     return fn()
   3281 except dialect.dbapi.Error as e:

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py:310, in Pool.connect(self)
    303 """Return a DBAPI connection from the pool.
    304 
    305 The connection is instrumented such that when its
   (...)
    308 
    309 """
--> 310 return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py:868, in _ConnectionFairy._checkout(cls, pool, threadconns, fairy)
    867 if not fairy:
--> 868     fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
    870     fairy._pool = pool

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py:476, in _ConnectionRecord.checkout(cls, pool)
    474 @classmethod
    475 def checkout(cls, pool):
--> 476     rec = pool._do_get()
    477     try:

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py:145, in QueuePool._do_get(self)
    144 except:
--> 145     with util.safe_reraise():
    146         self._dec_overflow()

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py:70, in safe_reraise.__exit__(self, type_, value, traceback)
     69     if not self.warn_only:
---> 70         compat.raise_(
     71             exc_value,
     72             with_traceback=exc_tb,
     73         )
     74 else:

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py:208, in raise_(***failed resolving arguments***)
    207 try:
--> 208     raise exception
    209 finally:
    210     # credit to
    211     # https://cosmicpercolator.com/2016/01/13/exception-leaks-in-python-2-and-3/
    212     # as the __traceback__ object creates a cycle

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py:143, in QueuePool._do_get(self)
    142 try:
--> 143     return self._create_connection()
    144 except:

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py:256, in Pool._create_connection(self)
    254 """Called by subclasses to create a new ConnectionRecord."""
--> 256 return _ConnectionRecord(self)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py:371, in _ConnectionRecord.__init__(self, pool, connect)
    370 if connect:
--> 371     self.__connect()
    372 self.finalize_callback = deque()

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py:665, in _ConnectionRecord.__connect(self)
    664 except Exception as e:
--> 665     with util.safe_reraise():
    666         pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py:70, in safe_reraise.__exit__(self, type_, value, traceback)
     69     if not self.warn_only:
---> 70         compat.raise_(
     71             exc_value,
     72             with_traceback=exc_tb,
     73         )
     74 else:

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py:208, in raise_(***failed resolving arguments***)
    207 try:
--> 208     raise exception
    209 finally:
    210     # credit to
    211     # https://cosmicpercolator.com/2016/01/13/exception-leaks-in-python-2-and-3/
    212     # as the __traceback__ object creates a cycle

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py:661, in _ConnectionRecord.__connect(self)
    660 self.starttime = time.time()
--> 661 self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
    662 pool.logger.debug("Created new connection %r", connection)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\create.py:590, in create_engine.<locals>.connect(connection_record)
    589             return connection
--> 590 return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py:597, in DefaultDialect.connect(self, *cargs, **cparams)
    595 def connect(self, *cargs, **cparams):
    596     # inherits the docstring from interfaces.Dialect.connect
--> 597     return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py:358, in Connection.__init__(self, user, password, host, database, unix_socket, port, charset, collation, sql_mode, read_default_file, conv, use_unicode, client_flag, cursorclass, init_command, connect_timeout, read_default_group, autocommit, local_infile, max_allowed_packet, defer_connect, auth_plugin_map, read_timeout, write_timeout, bind_address, binary_prefix, program_name, server_public_key, ssl, ssl_ca, ssl_cert, ssl_disabled, ssl_key, ssl_verify_cert, ssl_verify_identity, compress, named_pipe, passwd, db)
    357 else:
--> 358     self.connect()

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py:711, in Connection.connect(self, sock)
    710         print(exc.traceback)
--> 711     raise exc
    713 # If e is neither DatabaseError or IOError, It's a bug.
    714 # But raising AssertionError hides original error.
    715 # So just reraise it.

OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '@localhost' ([Errno 11003] getaddrinfo failed)")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[70], line 7
      4 db_host = 'localhost'
      5 db_name = 'atliq_tshirts'
----> 7 db = SQLDatabase.from_uri(f"mysql+pymysql://{db_user}:{db_password}@{db_host}/{db_name}")

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\langchain\utilities\sql_database.py:125, in SQLDatabase.from_uri(cls, database_uri, engine_args, **kwargs)
    123 """Construct a SQLAlchemy engine from URI."""
    124 _engine_args = engine_args or {}
--> 125 return cls(create_engine(database_uri, **_engine_args), **kwargs)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\langchain\utilities\sql_database.py:61, in SQLDatabase.__init__(self, engine, schema, metadata, ignore_tables, include_tables, sample_rows_in_table_info, indexes_in_table_info, custom_table_info, view_support, max_string_length)
     58 if include_tables and ignore_tables:
     59     raise ValueError("Cannot specify both include_tables and ignore_tables")
---> 61 self._inspector = inspect(self._engine)
     63 # including view support by adding the views as well as tables to the all
     64 # tables list if view_support is True
     65 self._all_tables = set(
     66     self._inspector.get_table_names(schema=schema)
     67     + (self._inspector.get_view_names(schema=schema) if view_support else [])
     68 )

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\inspection.py:64, in inspect(subject, raiseerr)
     62 if reg is True:
     63     return subject
---> 64 ret = reg(subject)
     65 if ret is not None:
     66     break

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\reflection.py:182, in Inspector._engine_insp(bind)
    180 @inspection._inspects(Engine)
    181 def _engine_insp(bind):
--> 182     return Inspector._construct(Inspector._init_engine, bind)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\reflection.py:117, in Inspector._construct(cls, init, bind)
    114     cls = bind.dialect.inspector
    116 self = cls.__new__(cls)
--> 117 init(self, bind)
    118 return self

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\reflection.py:128, in Inspector._init_engine(self, engine)
    126 def _init_engine(self, engine):
    127     self.bind = self.engine = engine
--> 128     engine.connect().close()
    129     self._op_context_requires_connect = True
    130     self.dialect = self.engine.dialect

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py:3234, in Engine.connect(self, close_with_result)
   3219 def connect(self, close_with_result=False):
   3220     """Return a new :class:`_engine.Connection` object.
   3221 
   3222     The :class:`_engine.Connection` object is a facade that uses a DBAPI
   (...)
   3231 
   3232     """
-> 3234     return self._connection_cls(self, close_with_result=close_with_result)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py:96, in Connection.__init__(self, engine, connection, close_with_result, _branch_from, _execution_options, _dispatch, _has_events, _allow_revalidate)
     91     self._has_events = _branch_from._has_events
     92 else:
     93     self._dbapi_connection = (
     94         connection
     95         if connection is not None
---> 96         else engine.raw_connection()
     97     )
     99     self._transaction = self._nested_transaction = None
    100     self.__savepoint_seq = 0

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py:3313, in Engine.raw_connection(self, _connection)
   3291 def raw_connection(self, _connection=None):
   3292     """Return a "raw" DBAPI connection from the connection pool.
   3293 
   3294     The returned object is a proxied version of the DBAPI
   (...)
   3311 
   3312     """
-> 3313     return self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, _connection)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py:3283, in Engine._wrap_pool_connect(self, fn, connection)
   3281 except dialect.dbapi.Error as e:
   3282     if connection is None:
-> 3283         Connection._handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection(
   3284             e, dialect, self
   3285         )
   3286     else:
   3287         util.raise_(
   3288             sys.exc_info()[1], with_traceback=sys.exc_info()[2]
   3289         )

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py:2117, in Connection._handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection(cls, e, dialect, engine)
   2115     util.raise_(newraise, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e)
   2116 elif should_wrap:
-> 2117     util.raise_(
   2118         sqlalchemy_exception, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e
   2119     )
   2120 else:
   2121     util.raise_(exc_info[1], with_traceback=exc_info[2])

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py:208, in raise_(***failed resolving arguments***)
    205     exception.__cause__ = replace_context
    207 try:
--> 208     raise exception
    209 finally:
    210     # credit to
    211     # https://cosmicpercolator.com/2016/01/13/exception-leaks-in-python-2-and-3/
    212     # as the __traceback__ object creates a cycle
    213     del exception, replace_context, from_, with_traceback

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py:3280, in Engine._wrap_pool_connect(self, fn, connection)
   3278 dialect = self.dialect
   3279 try:
-> 3280     return fn()
   3281 except dialect.dbapi.Error as e:
   3282     if connection is None:

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py:310, in Pool.connect(self)
    302 def connect(self):
    303     """Return a DBAPI connection from the pool.
    304 
    305     The connection is instrumented such that when its
   (...)
    308 
    309     """
--> 310     return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py:868, in _ConnectionFairy._checkout(cls, pool, threadconns, fairy)
    865 @classmethod
    866 def _checkout(cls, pool, threadconns=None, fairy=None):
    867     if not fairy:
--> 868         fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
    870         fairy._pool = pool
    871         fairy._counter = 0

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py:476, in _ConnectionRecord.checkout(cls, pool)
    474 @classmethod
    475 def checkout(cls, pool):
--> 476     rec = pool._do_get()
    477     try:
    478         dbapi_connection = rec.get_connection()

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py:145, in QueuePool._do_get(self)
    143         return self._create_connection()
    144     except:
--> 145         with util.safe_reraise():
    146             self._dec_overflow()
    147 else:

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py:70, in safe_reraise.__exit__(self, type_, value, traceback)
     68     self._exc_info = None  # remove potential circular references
     69     if not self.warn_only:
---> 70         compat.raise_(
     71             exc_value,
     72             with_traceback=exc_tb,
     73         )
     74 else:
     75     if not compat.py3k and self._exc_info and self._exc_info[1]:
     76         # emulate Py3K's behavior of telling us when an exception
     77         # occurs in an exception handler.

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py:208, in raise_(***failed resolving arguments***)
    205     exception.__cause__ = replace_context
    207 try:
--> 208     raise exception
    209 finally:
    210     # credit to
    211     # https://cosmicpercolator.com/2016/01/13/exception-leaks-in-python-2-and-3/
    212     # as the __traceback__ object creates a cycle
    213     del exception, replace_context, from_, with_traceback

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py:143, in QueuePool._do_get(self)
    141 if self._inc_overflow():
    142     try:
--> 143         return self._create_connection()
    144     except:
    145         with util.safe_reraise():

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py:256, in Pool._create_connection(self)
    253 def _create_connection(self):
    254     """Called by subclasses to create a new ConnectionRecord."""
--> 256     return _ConnectionRecord(self)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py:371, in _ConnectionRecord.__init__(self, pool, connect)
    369 self.__pool = pool
    370 if connect:
--> 371     self.__connect()
    372 self.finalize_callback = deque()

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py:665, in _ConnectionRecord.__connect(self)
    663     self.fresh = True
    664 except Exception as e:
--> 665     with util.safe_reraise():
    666         pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
    667 else:
    668     # in SQLAlchemy 1.4 the first_connect event is not used by
    669     # the engine, so this will usually not be set

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py:70, in safe_reraise.__exit__(self, type_, value, traceback)
     68     self._exc_info = None  # remove potential circular references
     69     if not self.warn_only:
---> 70         compat.raise_(
     71             exc_value,
     72             with_traceback=exc_tb,
     73         )
     74 else:
     75     if not compat.py3k and self._exc_info and self._exc_info[1]:
     76         # emulate Py3K's behavior of telling us when an exception
     77         # occurs in an exception handler.

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py:208, in raise_(***failed resolving arguments***)
    205     exception.__cause__ = replace_context
    207 try:
--> 208     raise exception
    209 finally:
    210     # credit to
    211     # https://cosmicpercolator.com/2016/01/13/exception-leaks-in-python-2-and-3/
    212     # as the __traceback__ object creates a cycle
    213     del exception, replace_context, from_, with_traceback

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py:661, in _ConnectionRecord.__connect(self)
    659 try:
    660     self.starttime = time.time()
--> 661     self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
    662     pool.logger.debug("Created new connection %r", connection)
    663     self.fresh = True

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\create.py:590, in create_engine.<locals>.connect(connection_record)
    588         if connection is not None:
    589             return connection
--> 590 return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py:597, in DefaultDialect.connect(self, *cargs, **cparams)
    595 def connect(self, *cargs, **cparams):
    596     # inherits the docstring from interfaces.Dialect.connect
--> 597     return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py:358, in Connection.__init__(self, user, password, host, database, unix_socket, port, charset, collation, sql_mode, read_default_file, conv, use_unicode, client_flag, cursorclass, init_command, connect_timeout, read_default_group, autocommit, local_infile, max_allowed_packet, defer_connect, auth_plugin_map, read_timeout, write_timeout, bind_address, binary_prefix, program_name, server_public_key, ssl, ssl_ca, ssl_cert, ssl_disabled, ssl_key, ssl_verify_cert, ssl_verify_identity, compress, named_pipe, passwd, db)
    356     self._sock = None
    357 else:
--> 358     self.connect()

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py:711, in Connection.connect(self, sock)
    709     if DEBUG:
    710         print(exc.traceback)
--> 711     raise exc
    713 # If e is neither DatabaseError or IOError, It's a bug.
    714 # But raising AssertionError hides original error.
    715 # So just reraise it.
    716 raise

OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '@localhost' ([Errno 11003] getaddrinfo failed)")
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use f-string. Also there is a bug in your code which should be `{host}`.

The code can run:

```
SQLDatabase.from_uri(f"mysql+pymysql://{username}:{password}@{host}/{database}",sample_rows_in_table_info = 3)
```

Comment: I've used f-string and it gives the same error. Sorry for the typo here, but I did use `{host}`. I've also tried passing strings instead of the declared variables. still no luck.
When I create an engine with the same uri, it creates the engine without error. 
```SQLDatabase(engine)``` gives this same error.

Comment: `create_engine`will not check your engine uri's availability. Maybe you can paste the error with f-string.

Comment: Hi
just updated the question with the new error log

Comment: Done! 
Thanks for that. used urllibparse to get a string for my password with special characters, and used the f-string.

Answer (score 0):

```
"Can't connect to MySQL server on '@localhost' ([Errno 11003] getaddrinfo failed)"
```

This error is usually caused by using a password which has a `@` character in it. This screws up URI parsing. The workaround is to avoid using a password with `@` in it.

Alternatively, you can create the URL object with [`sqlalchemy.engine.URL.create()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.engine.URL.create), which avoids quoting issues. Reading the source code of LangChain, it passes the provided URI to create_engine(), so a URL object should work just as well as a string.

Comment: Done! 
Thanks for that. used urllibparse to get a string for my password with special characters, and used the f-string.

Comment: @GaganDehal You're welcome - do you mind accepting it if this answer helped you?